# how to add an array inside another in PHP?

Tags: php, laravel

I am using laravel.
How can I create a new array and have the properties of another.
Example the carriage array can have 3 rows that are of the "info" properties, but the brand is added.

```
    $info = [
      ['id' => 1, 'color'=> 'blue'],
      ['id' => 2, 'color'=> 'red'],
      ['id' => 3, 'color'=> 'yellow'],
    ];

    $car = [
      ['id' => 'id_info', 'brand'=> 'toyota', 'color' => 'color_info']  
    ];
```

Comment: you can use array_merge which can combine both arrays but the brand is only added to the last entry

Comment: Array ( [0] => Array ( [id] => 1 [color] => blue ) [1] => Array ( [id] => 2 [color] => red ) [2] => Array ( [id] => 3 [color] => yellow ) [3] => Array ( [id] => id_info [brand] => toyota [color] => color_info ) )

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop through array and add key to each array

```
$info = [
      ['id' => 1, 'color'=> 'blue'],
      ['id' => 2, 'color'=> 'red'],
      ['id' => 3, 'color'=> 'yellow'],
    ];
$newInfo = [];
foreach($info as $eachInfo){
  $newInfo[] = array_merge($eachInfo,['brand' => 'toyota']);
}

dd($newInfo);
```

Will produce output like

```
array:3 [
  0 => array:3 [
    "id" => 1
    "color" => "blue"
    "brand" => "toyota"
  ]
  1 => array:3 [
    "id" => 2
    "color" => "red"
    "brand" => "toyota"
  ]
  2 => array:3 [
    "id" => 3
    "color" => "yellow"
    "brand" => "toyota"
  ]
]
```